# How to integrate gitlab or github account setup with laravel in localhost or 127.0.0.1:8000?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I keep getting invalid URL while integrating gitscrum locally on MAMP..?

Error Log for github is

**ClientException**
Client error: `GET https://api.github.com/user?access_token=` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
"message": "Bad credentials",
"documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}

**Error log for gitlab** -> 
The redirect URI included is not valid. It shows this, that's all.

How can I make authentication in my local serve on MAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/using-github-authentication-for-login-with-laravel-socialite

Following this tutorial should get you up and running even from localhost.

Or you should post your Code for that, otherwise it's hard to find your mistake.

Comment: Really Thanks for your answer. I found the solution according to the link, just URI mismatching error.